# nodejs, require process returns undefined

Tags: node.js

I'm new on nodejs, and I have problems trying to use process

```
var process = require('process');
process.stdin.resume();
```

The reason is process is undefined, I've tried to install the package via npm install -g process but it does not fix this problem, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

process is a native global object. You don't need to require it to use it. See [here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process)

Comment: But if I'm getting this message ReferenceError: Can't find variable: process

Comment: @aldokkani “_The `process` object provides information about, and control over, the current Node.js process._ `import process from 'node:process';`” is all I see, though.